# Do webpack bundles get cached?

Tags: javascript, caching, webpack

If you go to a index.html and it runs `bundle.js`, will it get cached in the browser and not need to be downloaded again unless the index.html gets a new one bundle next time someone deploys?

Comment: That depends, is `bundle.js` hosted locally? Or is it being grabbed from an external source?

Comment: That completely depends on how the webserver serving the file is set up.